# Any way to keep gradient attached at top when scrolling?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uikit

I have a scroll view attached to superview(not safe area) and inside it there is a gradient filled view at top. However when i swipe up, the gradient gets pulled down and white background is showed at top of the screen. Adding a gradient behind to cover up doesn't work. Is there any way when I pull down, the gradient expands or something? So the top of it stays connected?[image: Here's how I want it to look when view loads]

[image: Here how it looks when I pull down scrollView]

Instead I want it to stay connected at top while the bottom of gradient expands if I pull down. I have seen even on twitter app, when you pull down, the header expands and starts to blur. However that seems to be tableView, I want same effect in scrollView without the blur, just the expansion or maybe I won't mind the blur too.

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic.

Comment: You may check [this](https://johncodeos.com/how-to-make-a-stretchy-header-in-ios-using-swift/)